# keystonejs redirect after signin not working with function as second parameter

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, redirect, keystonejs

**Use case**

I have some custom form for the frontend, that needs a signed in user.
Therefore I use keystone.js' own "requireUser" middleware.
After the user has signed in, to access the site, the default behaviour is to show the admin UI at "/keystone" - however I want to redirect back to the previous frontend page, so the user can start filling in the form.

**What works**

In keystone.js, in the file with the exact same name, you can set

```
keystone.set('signin redirect', '/');
```

which redirects to the home page after the signin.

**What I need**

However, what I need is to set the url to redirect to dynamically, but when I do this, the function is never called:

```
keystone.set('signin redirect', function(req, res){
    var url = req.session.returnTo || '/';
    res.redirect(url);
});
```

The req.session.returnTo parameter is set in the "middleware.js" file previously mentioned, by taking the req.path property from the frontend page:

```
exports.requireUser = function (req, res, next) {
if (!req.user) {
    req.flash('error', 'Please sign in to access this page.');
    req.session.returnTo = req.path;
    res.redirect('/keystone/signin');
} else {
    next();
}
};
```

**My temporary workaround**

In keystone/admin/server/routes/signin.js I extend the redirect property of the locals object from

```
redirect: keystone.get('signin redirect'),
```

to

```
redirect: (typeof keystone.get('signin redirect') === 'string') ? 
keystone.get('signin redirect') : keystone.get('signin redirect')(req, res),
```

I am aware this is not an ideal solution, but since I am still learning about keystone.js, do you know a better way of handling this?

Notice: the same redirect strategy works when setting the "signout redirect" key (to both a string or a function as second parameter) so I guess this must be something that was forgotten to implement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@hajn 
Following #1489 issue on Keystone project, there is no ideal solution as of now. Documentation didn't provide the function params properly (I'm considering that as an issue). So, I've reopened the issue 3 days back.

Comment: hey I saw your comment on the project issues but didn't have time to come back to it, feel free to add the solution from the thread so this question has a solution

Answer (score 1):

Change routes/middleware.js replacing the method exports.requireUser as follows:

```
/**
Prevents people from accessing protected pages when they're not signed in
*/
exports.requireUser = function (req, res, next) {

    if (!req.user) {

        req.flash('error', 'Please sign in to access this page.');

        if(req.url) {

            res.redirect('/keystone/signin?from='+req.url);

        } else {

            res.redirect('/keystone/signin');
        }

    } else {

        next();
    }
};
```

From any URL pointing to /keystone/signin, include a from parameter in the query string, as so:

```
<a href="/keystone/signin?from=/">Log in</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/keystone/signin?from=/my/page/that/requires/login">Log in</a>
```